# on Hadoop, Is it possible to increase map (not maptask or node!) when running application (like WordCount or Pi Estimator)

Tags: hadoop

I'm beginner programmer and hadoop learner.

I'm testing hadoop full distribute mode using 5 PC(has Dual-core cpu and ram 2G)
 before starting maptask and hdfs, I knew that I must configure file(etc/hosts on Ip, hostname and hadoop folder/conf/masters,slaves file) so I finished configured that file.
 and then,

I have one Question

Is it Possible to increase(or add) map(not mapTask or node!)when running application (like WordCount or Pi Estimator)?

For example, I'm running Pi Estimator application using 10 map,iteration 100,000,000.

On the way to Running Application, I feeled that it's so slow , so I want to increase map,even if hadoop state is running. is it Possible? if it's true, Please tell me the way.

Or before running application, Can I configured config files (like hdfs-site.xml or mapred-site.xml) to increase map dynamically when running application?

hadoop master users on stack overflow community, Please tell me detail about the truth.

Comment: `increase(or add) map(not mapTask or node!)` It is not clear as to what do you mean by a MAP. Probably this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) might help you understand the Mapper.

Comment: Its simple !

When I input Hadoop command,for example, hadoop jar hadoop-example-1.0.4 Pi 
10(<-this is map) 100000000(this is iteration) 
then hadoop operates Pi estimator using 10 map.
I want to know that when hadoop running application , Can I add maps to running application?

Answer (score 0):

you can set mapred.map.tasks and give the job a hint about how many mappers you want but its only a hint and hadoop won't necessarily obey it. you can set the number of maximum concurrent map tasks running at once by setting mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum,

[Setting the number of map tasks and reduce tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885441/setting-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks)

[How to increase the mappers and reducers in hadoop according to number of instances used to increase the performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448204/how-to-increase-the-mappers-and-reducers-in-hadoop-according-to-number-of-instan)

Comment: No,No,No, I don't tell abount tasks per map.
I only wondered about Can I add to maps on running application ( hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4 Pi 10(<-this is number I want to increase when running state)10000000 Not Maps per task

Comment: I see now. In that case, no i do not think it is possible to dynamically add mappers to a running job.